# How to verify if an rpm was installed from scratch or upgraded?

Tags: linux, redhat, yum, rpm

we installed the following rpm's via yum on redhat version 5

```
# rpm -qa --last | head -10
  kernel-headers-2.6.18-408.el5                 Wed May 18 13:33:59 2016
  bind-utils-9.3.6-25.P1.el5_11.6               Wed May 18 13:33:59 2016
  redhat-release-5Server-5.11.0.2               Wed May 18 13:33:58 2016
  nss-3.19.1-4.el5_11                           Wed May 18 13:33:58 2016
  nspr-4.10.8-2.el5_11                          Wed May 18 13:33:58 2016
  bind-libs-9.3.6-25.P1.el5_11.6                Wed May 18 13:33:58 2016
  kernel-2.6.18-409.el5                         Wed May 18 04:13:58 2016
```

How can I tell if these RPMs were installed from scratch or just upgraded?

I try by **rpm -qi**

but from **rpm -qi** , we not get the info if rpm was installed from scratch or upgraded.

Secondly,  if an rpm was upgraded then how can I downgrade it to the previous version?

example when I try to downgrade:

```
 yum downgrade openssh-server-5.3p1-117.el6.x86_64

 Loaded plugins: product-id, rhnplugin, security, subscription-manager
 This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or RHN Satellite.
 Setting up Downgrade Process
 Only Upgrade available on package: openssh-server-5.3p1-117.el6.x86_64
 Nothing to do



  yum list 'openssh-server'

  Loaded plugins: product-id, rhnplugin, security, subscription-manager
  This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or RHN Satellite.

  openssh-server.x86_64      5.3p1-117.el6
  Available Packages
  penssh-server.x86_64   5.3p1-118.1.el6_8
```

Comment: Maybe you should use `yum` to check it. It keeps a history of what it's done.

Comment: but how can identify if the rpm/patch is from scratch or upgrade , yum downgrade can’t downgrade scratch patch/rpm

Comment: An upgrade is just a removal and installation in one transaction, so there's no reason you can't downgrade a package that was simply installed. It doesn't have to have been installed at a lower version to be eligible for downgrade.

Comment: please see my update , about  yum downgrade

Comment: Is there lower version package for `openssh-server`? What does `yum list 'openssh-server*'` show?

Comment: see my update regarding you remark

Comment: There likely isn't any lower versioned packages available for `openssh-server`, hence why it's saying that. I've tried the commands myself and it should let you run `yum downgrade openssh-server` to downgrade it (or at least *try* downgrading it; it's probably going to throw a bunch of dependency errors), but *only* if the packages exist in the repository or are specified on the command-line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Apparently](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/64069) (no experience since I am not a `yum` user), `yum` keeps a history of transactions, which you can list using

```
yum history
```

or

```
yum history list
```

to get a list of transactons and then

```
yum history info <transaction id>
```

which will tell you what was installed/updated etc

and you can undo transactions using

```
yum history undo <transaction index>
```

Purely based on the `rpm` commands, afaik there are no means to know whether an rpm was installed from scratch or updated. I don't know either whether yum keeps a version of all rpms it once installed. If not; there is no guarantee you can undo a certain transaction. Suppose package-1 was installed from the install cd (or any other repository that is not available anymore); then updated to package-2. Suppose you want to undo that update transaction; that would be only possible if you have package-1.rpm available; which is not always (and mostly not) the case.

Suppose you want to downgrade an rpm; you can search (`yum search`; or [rpm search](http://rpm.pbone.net/) or...) a lower version of the rpm you want and install that one. That will always work (supposing you have all the correct dependencies); using `yum`, `rpm` or others.